# JQUERY Int and String Addition

Tags: javascript, string, math, int, addition

Ok I have the following "script":

```
var text = '24 - 08';
var value = text.split(" - ");


var result = 24 - value[0];
result = result + value[1];
alert(result);
```

http://jsbin.com/amusaw/edit#javascript,html

So the result of this simple math thing is 0 with parseInt or 008 without it. It should be 8.
I tried this with several different numbers (instead of 08, 04 or 05 etc...)
or 22 - 09.

Sometimes the result value is right and sometimes it's not.
I tried to apply parseInt to all "math operations" ... no success.
I think it's a tiny error, but I don't get it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify the base when parsing ints:

```
parseInt(value[0], 10);
parseInt(value[1], 10);
```

Whole code:

```
var text = '24 - 08';
var value = text.split(" - ");


var result = 24 - parseInt(value[0], 10);
result = result + parseInt(value[1], 10);
alert(result);
```

http://jsbin.com/amusaw/2/edit

When an string begins with a `0` parseInt assumes the number is octal (base 8). It's deprecated behaviour, but it is the way it behaves at any rate. The number `08` is invalid in octal since only the digits `0-7` exist, so it just returns `0`. It determines that the 8 isn't part of the number, it is just like seeing `0A` or `0T` (or any other non `0-7` character).

More on [parseInt(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). In fact you can find the `parseInt("08");` example that caused the problem for you right near the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to works using parseFloat instead of parseInt.
You can do :

```
var result = 24 - parseFloat(value[0]);
result = result + parseFloat(value[1]);
alert(result);
```

You can then convert to int with a parseInt.